# Angular 4 img src is not found

Tags: html, image, angular, src

I'm having a problem with sourcing an image with angular 4. It keeps telling me that the image is not found.

Folder structure:

```
app_folder/
app_component/
  - my_componenet
  - image_folder/
      - myimage
```

I am using the image in `mycomponent`. If in `mycomponent`, I insert it directly with:

```html
<img src="img/myimage.png"
```

This works fine, but I checked the html and it creates a hash. But my images have to be dynamically added to the html because they are part of a list. So, if I use:

```html
<img src="{{imagePath}}">
```

which is basically `img/myimage.png`, it doesn't work. If I use:

```html
<img [src]="imagePath">
```

It says `NOT FOUND (htttps://localhost/img/myimage.png)`. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr ? BTW `[src]="imagePath"` is the correct implementation for Angular 4

Comment: I guess that your path to the image is not correct!

Comment: @bhantol Yeah, I Know that's why I am losing my mind. my imagePath is like "img/myimage.png" and it says not found when I use [src]="imagePath".

Comment: If you can type the `htttps://localhost/img/myimage.png` in a separate window and it still says not found then as @YordanNikolov suggest it just does not exist regardless of angular.

Comment: I am getting the array of images from http request and pushing into array and displaying using ngfor . for the first set it works and after the page scroll dynamic fetching of images not working. Can you tell me wh

Comment: Check those paths were mapping properly towards the images.

Answer (score 101):

AngularJS

```
<img ng-src="{{imagePath}}">
```

Angular

```
<img [src]="imagePath">
```

Comment: 2/4 example not working for me
`<img [ERROR ->][src]="../assets/images/hellotravelindia-small.png">`

Comment: @HidaytRahman - Use like this - `src="assets/images/hellotravelindia-small.png"`

Comment: I am getting the array of images from http request and pushing into array and displaying using ngfor . for the first set it works and after the page scroll dynamic fetching of images not working. Can you tell me why

Answer (score 89):

Copy your images into the assets folder. Angular can only access static files like images and config files from assets folder.

Try like this: `<img src="assets/img/myimage.png">`

Comment: I am getting the array of images from http request and pushing into array and displaying using ngfor . for the first set it works and after the page scroll dynamic fetching of images not working. Can you tell me wh\

Comment: Yes exactly!! I was facing the same problem and your solution worked as a charm.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

Create image folder under the assets folder

```
<img src="assets/images/logo_poster.png">
```

Answer (score 16):

**Angular 4 to 8**

Either works

```
<img [src]="imageSrc" [alt]="imageAlt" />

<img src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="{{imageAlt}}" />
```

and the Component would be

```
export class sample Component implements OnInit {
   imageSrc = 'assets/images/iphone.png'  
   imageAlt = 'iPhone'
```

Tree structure:

```
-> src 
   -> app
   -> assets
      -> images
           'iphone.png'
```

Answer (score 8):

in your component assign a variable like,

```
export class AppComponent {
  netImage:any = "../assets/network.jpg";
  title = 'app';
}
```

use this netImage in your src to get the image, as given below,

```
<figure class="figure">
  <img [src]="netImage" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 6):

@Annk you can make a variable in the __component.ts file

myImage : string = "http://example.com/path/image.png";

and inside the __.component.html file you can use one of those 3 methods :

1 .

```
<div> <img src="{{myImage}}"> </div>
```

2 .

```
<div> <img [src]="myImage"/> </div>
```

3 .

```
<div> <img bind-src="myImage"/> </div>
```

Comment: Out of the three the first is the one for which both the IDE and lint scream at you the least.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the problem was that, somehow, the path was not recognized when was inserted in `src` by a variable. I had to create a variable like this:

```
path:any = require("../../img/myImage.png");
```

and then I can use it in `src`. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="images/no-record-found.png" width="50%" height="50%"/>
```

Your images folder and your index.html should be in same directory(follow following dir structure).
it will even work after build

Directory Structure

```
-src
    |-images
    |-index.html
    |-app
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular can only access static files like images and config files from assets folder. Nice way to download string path of remote stored image and load it to template.

```
  public concateInnerHTML(path: string): string {
     if(path){
        let front = "<img class='d-block' src='";
        let back = "' alt='slide'>";
        let result = front + path + back;
        return result;
     }
     return null;
  }
```

In a Component imlement DoCheck interface and past in it formula for database. Data base query is only a sample.

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
   this.concatedPathName = this.concateInnerHTML(database.query('src'));
}
```

And in html tamplate `<div [innerHtml]="concatedPathName"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the width for the image as default

```
 <img width="300" src="assets/company_logo.png">
```

its working for me based on all other alternate way.

Answer (score 1):

An important observation on how Angular 2, 2+ attribute bindings work.

The issue with `[src]="imagePath"` not working while the following do:

- `<img src="img/myimage.png">`
- `<img src={{imagePath}}>`

Is due your binding declaration, `[src]="imagePath"` is directly binded to Component's `this.imagePath` or if it's part of an ngFor loop, then `*each.imagePath`.

However, on the other two working options, you're either binding a string on HTML or allowing HTML to be binded to a variable that's yet to be defined.

HTML will not throw any error if you bind `<img src=garbage*Th_i$.ngs>`, however Angular will.

My recommendation is to **use an inline-if in case the variable might not be defined**, such as `<img [src]="!!imagePath ? imagePath : 'urlString'">`, which can be though of as `node.src = imagePath ? imagePath : 'something'`.

Avoid binding to possible missing variables or make good use of `*ngIf` in that element.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your.angular-cli.json under app -> assets:[] if you have included assets folder.

Or perhaps something here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2231, can help.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this code in angular to add the image path. if your images are under assets folder then.

```
<img src="../assets/images/logo.png" id="banner-logo" alt="Landing Page"/>
```

if not under the assets folder then you can use this code.

```
<img src="../images/logo.png" id="banner-logo" alt="Landing Page"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli includes the assets folder in the build options by default. I got this issue when the name of my images had spaces or dashes. 
For example :

- 'my-image-name.png' should be 'myImageName.png'
- 'my image name.png' should be 'myImageName.png'

If you put the image in the assets/img folder, then this line of code should work in your templates :

```
<img [alt]="My image name" src="./assets/img/myImageName.png'">
```

If the issue persist just check if your Angular-cli config file and be sure that your assets folder is added in the build options.

Answer (score 0):

Add in angular.json

```
  "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

And then use it like this:         `<img src={{imgPath}} alt="img"></div>`

And in ts:   `storyPath = 'assets/images/myImg.png';`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/google-body-ads.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem, I added src/app/types/types.d.ts with content:

```
declare module '*.png' {
    const value: any
    export default value
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
    const value: any
    export default value
}

declare module '*.svg' {
    const value: any
    export default value
}
```