# Angular Image src not updating although variable is populated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have the following code:

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="updateImage('image1.png')"></button>

<img src="{{selectedImage}}" alt="" />
```

app.component.ts:

```
selectedImage;

updateImage(image) {
    this.selectedImage = image;
}
```

My question is...If image url has been passed, why isn't the image src updating?

Comment: try binding it with [src]="selectedImage" and see if it works

Comment: it could be a path issue here, any errors in console?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040843/angular-4-img-src-is-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[src]` instead of src

```
<img [src]="selectedImage" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, ensure that your pathing is correct. The code looks good, but the app may not find your image. There would be an error 404 in your browser console if that were the case.

Try placing the image in your `assets` folder and linking it with `updateImage('/assets/image1.png')`