# Angular 8 Display image src stored as ng model in variable

Tags: html, angular, image, src, angular-ngmodel

I want to display image src as dynamic variable, I declared a default value as string in variable named displayedImage :

```
<div class="col-6 " style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="assets/cardsModels/Anniversaire.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**

```
this.displayedImage = 'assets/cardsModels/Anniversaire.pnf'
```

this.displayedImage declared in the constructor, the image not found and cannot be displayed !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Img src is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040843/angular-4-img-src-is-not-working)

Comment: you might want to use `Anniversaire.png` and not `.pnf`

Comment: oh yes .png XD, my mistake , thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your question is to change html like (using data binding):

```
<div class="col-6 " style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img [src]="displayedImage" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And fix the typo from:

```
this.displayedImage = 'assets/cardsModels/Anniversaire.pnf'
```

to:

```
this.displayedImage = 'assets/cardsModels/Anniversaire.png'
```

Answer (score 4):

just use your variable `displayedImage` in `src` for an image:

```
<div class="col-6 " style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img [src]="displayedImage" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can use curly braces `{{ displayedImage }}`:

```
<div class="col-6 " style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <img src={{displayedImage}} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```